# How to transform List<List<String[]>> into 2 List<List<String>> that seperate its text & its IDs in Java?

Tags: java

Ok, Here is my problem. I have a `List<List<String[]>> mainList`, the `mainList` has 7 `List<String[]> subLists` as displayed in the below table:

```
List subList1:
[iPhone 2G, Apple Inc., 117913, 117973]
[iPhone 3G, Apple Inc., 117914, 117973]
[iPhone 3G, Apple Inc., 117914, 117973]
[iPhone 4, Apple Inc., 117916, 117973]

List subList2:
[iPhone 2G, Foxconn, 117913, 118004]
[iPhone 3G, Foxconn, 117914, 118004]
[iPhone 3GS, Foxconn, 117915, 118004]

List subList3:
[iPhone 2G, 1, 117913, 118033]
[iPhone 3G, 2, 117914, 73550]
[iPhone 3GS, 2, 117915, 73550]

List subList4:
[iPhone 2G, 2007-06-29, 117913, 117992]
[iPhone 3G, 2008-07-11, 117914, 117993]
[iPhone 3GS, 2009-06-19, 117915, 118043]

List subList5:
[iPhone 2G, 2008-07-11, 117913, 117993]
[iPhone 3G, 2010-06-07, 117914, 118034]
[iPhone 3GS, 2012-09-12, 117915, 118044]
[iPhone 4, 2013-09-10, 117916, 118060]

List subList6:
[iPhone 3G, iPhone 2G, 117914, 117913]
[iPhone 3GS, iPhone 3G, 117915, 117914]
[iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS, 117916, 117915]

List subList7:
[iPhone 2G, iPhone 3G, 117913, 117914]
[iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS, 117914, 117915]
[iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, 117915, 117916]
[iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, 117916, 117917]
```

**Note**: in each array in `subList`, there are 4 separate strings. The 1st 2 strings are any text & can be duplicated, whereas the 2 last strings are the uniqueIDs of the 2 texts.

For example, look at this array `[iPhone 2G, Apple Inc., 117913, 117973]` we can see that `iPhone 2G` has its `uniqueID = 117913` & `Apple Inc.` has its `uniqueID=117973`

**Requirement:** I want to bring the above `mainList` into these 2 `List<List<String>>`:

-1. Text Only: `List<List<String>> textOnlyList`

```
If you `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(textOnlyList.toArray());`, it will show output like this:

[[iPhone 2G, Apple Inc., Foxconn, 1, 2007-06-29, 2008-07-11, null , iPhone 3G], 
[iPhone 3G, Apple Inc., Foxconn, 2, 2008-07-11, 2010-06-07, iPhone 2G, iPhone 3GS], 
[iPhone 3GS, Apple Inc., Foxconn, 2, 2009-06-19, 2012-09-12, iPhone 3G, iPhone 4], 
[iPhone 4, Apple Inc., null, null, null, 2013-09-10, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4S]]
```

-2. UniqueID Only: `List<List<String>> idOnlyList`

```
If you `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(idOnlyList.toArray());`, it will show output like this:

[[117913, 117973, 118004, 118033, 117992, 117993, null, 117914], 
[117914, 117973, 118004, 73550, 117993, 118034, 117913, 117915], 
[117915, 117973, 118004, 73550, 118043, 118044, 117914, 117916], 
[117916, 117973, null, null, null, 118060, 117915, 117917]]
```

I did try but my solution is quite complicated, error -prone & it had a bug that is if all the data is even then it show ok, but if the data is not even (ie variable, ex, subList could contain 3 or 2 records not just always 4 records) then it got messed up.

So you code need to handle the variable.

I hope you can help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Looking at `List<List<String[]>>` it smells like time to redesign your type.

Comment: my app is amost finished, there is no time to redesign, sorry for that

Comment: You don't have time *not* to do it. All those strings belong in a `Phone` class, and it's going to be a nightmare debugging and maintaining that spaghetti.

Comment: it should have an elegant solution for it, since it following a certain structure.